# Exception handling when errors may occur in main program or in cleanup

Tags: python, exception

This is with Python 2.6.6 (default) on Debian Squeeze. Consider the following Python code.

```
import sys
try:
    raise Exception("error in main")
    pass
except:
    exc_info = sys.exc_info()
finally:
    try:
        print "cleanup - always run"
        raise Exception("error in cleanup")
    except:
        import traceback
        print >> sys.stderr, "Error in cleanup"
        traceback.print_exc()
    if 'exc_info' in locals():
        raise exc_info[0], exc_info[1], exc_info[2]

print "exited normally"
```

The error obtained is

```
Error in cleanup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in <module>
Exception: error in cleanup
cleanup - always run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
Exception: error in main
```

The idea is to cope with a situation where either some code or the cleanup of that code (which is always run) or both, gives an error. There is some discussion of this, for example, by Ian Bicking in [Re-raising Exceptions](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2007/09/12/re-raising-exceptions/). At the end of that post, (see `Update:`) he describes how to handle the similar case of code + rollback/revert (only run in case of error).

I fiddled with this and came up with the code above, which is a bit of a monstrosity. In particular, if there is *only* an error in
cleanup (commenting out `raise Exception("error in main")`), the code still exits normally, though it does print out a traceback. Currently, I'm giving the non-cleanup error priority, so it gets to stop the program.

Ideally I'd like either error to stop the program, but that doesn't seem to easy to arrange. Python seems to only want to raise one error, losing the others if any, and by default it is usually the last one. Rearranging this gives rise to convolutions like above.

Also the use of `locals()` is a bit ugly. Can one do better?

EDIT: [srgerg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8699141/350713) introduced me to the notion of the context managers and the `with` keyword. In addition to [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), the other relevant bits of documentation I found are (in no particular order).
[Context Manager Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types), [The with statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with), and http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers. This certainly seems like a big improvement on previous approaches to this, i.e. spaghetti code involving trys, excepts, and finallys.

To summarize, there are two things that I want such a solution to give me.

1. The ability for an exception in either the main code or in the
   cleanup to stop the program in its tracks. Context managers do this,
   because if the body of the with loop has an exception and the body of
   the **exit** does not, then that exception is propagated.
   If **exit** throws an exception and the body of the with loop does not,
   then that is propagated. if both throw an exception, then the **exit**
   exception is propagated and the one from the body of the while loop is
   suppressed. This is all documented i.e. from
   [Context Manager Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types),

   > contextmanager.**exit**(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
   >
   > Exit the runtime context and return a Boolean flag indicating if any exception that occurred should be suppressed. [...]
   >   Returning a true value from this method will cause the with statement to suppress the exception and continue execution with the
   >   statement immediately following the with statement. Otherwise the exception continues propagating after this method has finished
   >   executing. Exceptions that occur during execution of this method will replace any exception that occurred in the body of the with
   >   statement. [...] The exception passed in should never be reraised explicitly. instead, this method should return a false value to
   >   indicate that the method completed successfully and does not want to suppress the raised exception.
2. If there are exceptions in both places, I want to see tracebacks
   from both, even if technically only one exception is thrown. This is
   true based on experimentation, because if both throw an exception,
   then the **exit** exception is propagated, but the traceback from the body
   of the while loop is still printed, as in
   [srgerg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8699141/350713).
   However, I can't find this documented
   anywhere, which is unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, you'd use the python [with statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) to handle the cleanup within the `try ... except` block, which would look something like this:

```
class Something(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print "Entering"

    def __exit__(self, t, v, tr):
        print "cleanup - always runs"
        raise Exception("Exception occurred during __exit__")

try:
    with Something() as something:
        raise Exception("Exception occurred!")
except Exception, e:
    print e
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc(e)

print "Exited normally!"
```

When I run this, it prints:

```
Entering
cleanup - always runs
Exception occurred during __exit__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s3.py", line 11, in <module>
    raise Exception("Exception occurred!")
  File "s3.py", line 7, in __exit__
    raise Exception("Exception occurred during __exit__")
Exception: Exception occurred during __exit__
Exited normally!
```

Note, either exception will terminate the program, and can be dealt with in the `except` statement.

**Edit:** According to the with statement documentation linked to above, the `__exit__()` method should only raise an exception if there is an error inside `__exit__()` - that is, it should not re-raise the exception passed into it.

This is a problem if both the code in the `with` statement and the `__exit__()` method raise an exception. In that case, the exception that is caught in the except clause is the one raised in `__exit__()`. If you want the one raised in the with statement, you can do something like this:

```
class Something(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print "Entering"

    def __exit__(self, t, v, tr):
        print "cleanup - always runs"
        try:
            raise Exception("Exception occurred during __exit__")
        except Exception, e:
            if (t, v, tr) != (None, None, None):
                # __exit__ called with an existing exception
                return False
            else:
                # __exit__ called with NO existing exception
                raise

try:
    with Something() as something:
        raise Exception("Exception occurred!")
        pass
except Exception, e:
    print e
    traceback.print_exc(e)
    raise

print "Exited normally!"
```

This prints:

```
Entering
cleanup - always runs
Exception occurred!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s2.py", line 22, in <module>
    raise Exception("Exception occurred!")
Exception: Exception occurred!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s2.py", line 22, in <module>
   raise Exception("Exception occurred!")
Exception: Exception occurred!
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a completely new idea for me. Is the idea to have cleanup where you have `raise Exception("Exception occurred during __exit__")`? If so, can you add an appropriate `print "cleanup - always run"` or similar there?

Comment: I've added the print statement as requested.

Comment: Thanks, srgerg. I'm reading the PEP. I don't think I had heard or seen of the `with` keyword before, but maybe I just wasn't paying attention. Would one put the cleanup code in the enter or exit function, or does it not make a difference?

Comment: It does make a difference. The cleanup code should go in __exit__.

Comment: Ok, I see, enter is run before the main code, exit is run after the main code, so it corresponds to setup and cleanup, right?

Comment: Funny, when I run this, I don't get the `"Exception occurred!"`, just the one in exit. Which python version are you using? IOW: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in __exit__
Exception: Exception occurred during __exit__
Entering
cleanup - always runs
Exception occurred during __exit__
Exited normally!`

Comment: Sorry, I made changes to the code and forgot to update the output, I'll fix it now.

Comment: The problem I have is that I don't see the `raise Exception("Exception occurred!")` line in the output, and still don't, since you didn't change the code.

Comment: I've extended my answer with more information that should answer your question.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The output from your original code still looks wrong to me, though. Please confirm. Also, I think the documentation at http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types is useful.

Comment: I just copied and pasted my original code into a new file and re-ran it. I can confirm that the output is correct.

Comment: My apologies. I was running the scripts within emacs, as I usually do. Unfortunately, the output within emacs is different from what I get on the command line. On the command line I get what you do. This is quite disturbing, though. I wonder what is going on with emacs.

Answer (score 1):

A similar behaviour can be obtained by providing a customized [exception hook](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook):

```
import sys, traceback

def excepthook(*exc_info):
    print "cleanup - always run"
    raise Exception("error in cleanup")
    traceback.print_exception(*exc_info)
sys.excepthook = excepthook

raise Exception("error in main")
```

Example output:

```
cleanup - always run
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in excepthook
    raise Exception("error in cleanup")
Exception: error in cleanup

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    raise Exception("error in main")
Exception: error in main
```

In this example the code works as follows:

- If an exception isn't caught, `excepthook` is executed.
- Before printing the exception, `excepthook` runs some cleanup code (that was under `finally` in the original question).
- If an exception is raised in the hook, that exception is printed and, after that, the original exception is also printed.

Note: I haven't found any documentation regarding the printing of the original exception when something fails in the hook, but I've seen this behaviour in both cpython and jython. In particular, in cpython I've seen the following implementation:

```
void
PyErr_PrintEx(int set_sys_last_vars)
{
    ...
    hook = PySys_GetObject("excepthook");
    if (hook) {
        ...
        if (result == NULL) {
            ...
            PySys_WriteStderr("Error in sys.excepthook:\n");
            PyErr_Display(exception2, v2, tb2);
            PySys_WriteStderr("\nOriginal exception was:\n");
            PyErr_Display(exception, v, tb);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm unclear how this would work in the context of my script. Could you illustrate with a similar example, or perhaps the same example?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I've edited my answer to add more information. If I understood correctly, the example in your question and in my answer is actually the same.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation helped to clarify things. It seems the excepthook is run for all exceptions that are in scope, right? How can I localize it to  a single particular context? I don't want this to run under all circumstances.

Comment: Excepthook is executed for all uncaught exceptions. If you need this only in some places, you can revert `sys.excepthook` to its original value (available in `sys.__excepthook__`).

Comment: Ah, I see, so one would need to rewrite it from default and then back to default after its prospective use.

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close to a simple solution. Just use traceback.print_exc() in the first exception—then you don't have to handle the second exception anymore. Here's what that could look like:

```
error7 = False
try:
    raise Exception("error in main")
    pass
except:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
    error7 = True
finally:
    print "cleanup - always run"
    raise Exception("error in cleanup")
    if error7:
        raise SystemExit()

print "exited normally"
```

The information whether an exception was thrown is stored in `error7` and if that was the case, `SystemExit()` is raised at the end of the `finally` block.

Output with both `raise` statements enabled:

```
cleanup - always run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/backed-up to mozy/Scripts/sandbox.py", line 3, in <module>
    raise Exception("error in main")
Exception: error in main
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-10089b43dd14>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('G:/backed-up to mozy/Scripts/sandbox.py', wdir='G:/backed-up to mozy/Scripts')

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "G:/backed-up to mozy/Scripts/sandbox.py", line 11, in <module>
    raise Exception("error in cleanup")

Exception: error in cleanup
```