# Previous error being masked by current exception context

Tags: python, exception

The following is an example I found at the website for Doug Hellman in a file named "masking_exceptions_catch.py". I can't locate the link at the moment. The exception raised in throws() is discarded while that raised by cleanup() is reported.

In his article, Doug remarks that the handling is non-intuitive. Halfway expecting it to be a bug or limitation in the Python version at the time it was written (circa 2009), I ran it in the current production release of Python for the Mac (2.7.6). It still reports the exception from cleanup(). I find this somewhat amazing and would like to see a description of how it is actually correct or desirable behavior.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import traceback

def throws():
    raise RuntimeError('error from throws')

def nested():
    try:
        throws()
    except:
        try:
            cleanup()
        except:
            pass # ignore errors in cleanup
        raise # we want to re-raise the original error

def cleanup():
    raise RuntimeError('error from cleanup')

def main():
    try:
        nested()
        return 0
    except Exception, err:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

**Program output:**

```
$ python masking_exceptions_catch.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "masking_exceptions_catch.py", line 24, in main
    nested()
  File "masking_exceptions_catch.py", line 14, in nested
    cleanup()
  File "masking_exceptions_catch.py", line 20, in cleanup
    raise RuntimeError('error from cleanup')
RuntimeError: error from cleanup
```

Comment: I see there is an apparently-related discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698751/exception-handling-when-errors-may-occur-in-main-program-or-in-cleanup?rq=1. However, it would be nice to see a more basic one which involves minimal use of other programming concepts.

Comment: Thanks. I find that discussion to be rather inaccessible and thus am unable to determine whether it raises (ha) the same issue.

Comment: The workaround here is of course to `except Exception as e:` and then later `raise e` or similar.

Comment: I can circle back around tomorrow and write up an answer if nobody else does. The issue is a bit involved.

Comment: It might be interesting to see a further explanation, but at this point I can satisfy myself that the non-intuitive behavior is indeed undesirable and that, at least in Python 2, has been found difficult to fully address. I appreciate the answers and having a good experience w/ my first S/O post.

Comment: There are answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350671/inner-exception-with-traceback-in-python) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414744/python-exception-chaining).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Circling back around to answer.  I'll start by not answering your question. :-)

**Does this really work?**

```
def f():
    try:
        raise Exception('bananas!')
    except:
        pass
    raise
```

So, what does the above do?  Cue Jeopardy music.

---

Alright then, pencils down.

```
# python 3.3
      4     except:
      5         pass
----> 6     raise
      7 

RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise

# python 2.7
      1 def f():
      2     try:
----> 3         raise Exception('bananas!')
      4     except:
      5         pass

Exception: bananas!
```

Well, that was fruitful.  For fun, let's try naming the exception.

```
def f():
    try:
        raise Exception('bananas!')
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    raise e
```

What now?

```
# python 3.3
      4     except Exception as e:
      5         pass
----> 6     raise e
      7 

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment

# python 2.7
      4     except Exception as e:
      5         pass
----> 6     raise e
      7 

Exception: bananas!
```

Exception semantics changed pretty drastically between python 2 and 3.  But if python 2's behavior is at all surprising to you here, consider: it's basically in line with what python does everywhere else.

```
try:
    1/0
except Exception as e: 
    x=4
#can I access `x` here after the exception block?  How about `e`?
```

`try` and `except` are not scopes.  Few things are, actually, in python; we have the "LEGB Rule" to remember the four namespaces - Local, Enclosing, Global, Builtin.  Other blocks simply aren't scopes; I can happily declare `x` within a `for` loop and expect to still be able to reference it after that loop.

So, awkward.  Should exceptions be special-cased to be confined to their enclosing lexical block?  Python 2 says no, python 3 says [yes](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/#semantic-changes).  But I'm oversimplifying things here; bare `raise` is what you initially asked about, and the issues are closely related but not actually the same.  Python 3 *could* have mandated that named exceptions are scoped to their block without addressing the bare `raise` thing.

**What does bare `raise` *do‽***

Common usage is to use bare `raise` as a means to preserve the stack trace.  Catch, do logging/cleanup, reraise.  Cool, my cleanup code doesn't appear in the traceback, works 99.9% of the time.  But things can go south when we try to handle nested exceptions within an exception handler.  *Sometimes.* (see examples at the bottom for when it is/isn't a problem)

Intuitively, no-argument `raise` would properly handle nested exception handlers, and figure out the correct "current" exception to reraise.  That's not exactly reality, though.  Turns out that - getting into implementation details here - exception info is saved as a member of the current [frame object](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#frame-objects).  And in python 2, there's simply no plumbing to handle pushing/popping exception handlers on a stack within a single frame; there's just simply a field that contains the last exception, irrespective of any handling we may have done to it.  That's what bare `raise` grabs.

> ## 6.9. [The raise statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement)
>
> `raise_stmt ::=  "raise" [expression ["," expression ["," expression]]]`
>
> If no expressions are present, raise re-raises the last exception that
>   was active in the current **scope**.

So, yes, this is a problem deep within python 2 related to how traceback information is stored - in Highlander tradition, there can be only one (traceback object saved to a given stack frame).  As a consequence, bare `raise` reraises what the current frame believes is the "last" exception, which isn't necessarily the one that our human brains believe is the one specific to the lexically-nested exception block we're in at the time.  Bah, *scopes!*

**So, fixed in python 3?**

Yes.  How?  [New bytecode instruction](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/dis.html#opcode-POP_EXCEPT) (two, actually, there's another implicit one at the start of except handlers) but really who cares - it all "just works" intuitively.  Instead of getting `RuntimeError: error from cleanup`, your example code raises `RuntimeError: error from throws` as expected.

I can't give you an official reason why this was not included in python 2.  The issue has been known [since PEP 344](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0344/), which mentions Raymond Hettinger raising the issue in *2003*.  If I had to *guess*, fixing this is a breaking change (among other things, it affects the semantics of `sys.exc_info`), and that's often a good enough reason not to do it in a minor release.

**Options if you're on python 2:**

**1)** Name the exception you intend to reraise, and just deal with a line or two being added to the bottom of your stack trace.  Your example `nested` function becomes:

```
def nested():
    try:
        throws()
    except BaseException as e:
        try:
            cleanup()
        except:
            pass 
        raise e
```

And associated traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example", line 24, in main
    nested()
  File "example", line 17, in nested
    raise e
RuntimeError: error from throws
```

So, the traceback is altered, but it works.

**1.5)** Use the 3-argument version of `raise`.  A lot of people don't know about this one, and it is a legitimate (if clunky) way to preserve your stack trace.

```
def nested():
    try:
        throws()
    except:
        e = sys.exc_info()
        try:
            cleanup()
        except:
            pass 
        raise e[0],e[1],e[2]
```

`sys.exc_info` gives us a 3-tuple containing (type, value, traceback), which is exactly what the 3-argument version of `raise` takes.  Note that this 3-arg syntax only works in python 2.

**2)** Refactor your cleanup code such that it cannot *possibly* throw an unhandled exception.  Remember, it's all about **scopes** - move that `try/except` out of `nested` and into its own function.

```
def nested():
    try:
        throws()
    except:
        cleanup()
        raise

def cleanup():
    try:
        cleanup_code_that_totally_could_raise_an_exception()
    except:
        pass

def cleanup_code_that_totally_could_raise_an_exception():
    raise RuntimeError('error from cleanup')
```

Now you don't have to worry; since the exception never made it to `nested`'s scope, it won't interfere with the exception you intended to reraise.

**3)** Use bare `raise` like you were doing before you read all this and live with it; cleanup code doesn't usually raise exceptions, right?  :-)

Comment: Sorry about the delay in marking this as answered. It answered my question so thoroughly that it disappeared from my mind. ;-0